# iOS Swift Filter and Generating Model takes too much time

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, algorithm

I have 3 models and respective arrays

```
struct A {
    var id: String
    var bId: String
    var cId: String
}

struct B {
    var id: String
}

struct C {
    var id: String
}


let aList: [A] = [.......] // 100 elements

let bList: [B] = [.......] // 200 elements

let cList: [C] = [.......] // 300 elements
```

Now I need array of objects of struct '**FilterModel**' which will filter from '**bList**' and '**cList**' via Iterating '**aList**'

```
struct FilterModel {

    var objA: A
    var objB: B?
    var objC: C?

    init(objA: A,
         objB: B? = nil,
         objC: C? = nil) {

         self.objA = objA
         self.objB = objB
         self.objC = objC
    }
}

So far i have tried like this


var filterModels: [FilterModel] = []

for aModel in aList {

    let filterBModel = bList.filter { $0.id == aModel.bId }.first
    let filterCModel = cList.filter { $0.id == aModel.cId }.first

    let model =  FilterModel(objA: aModel,
                             objB: filterBModel,
                             objC: filterCModel)

    filterModels.append(model)
}
```

Is there any optimised or better way as it takes too much time?

Comment: First of all, change `bList.filter { $0.id == aModel.bId }.first` to `bList.first { $0.id == aModel.bId }`. But the performance will be terrible anyway.

Comment: From where you are getting bList and cList arrays ? You are creating them ?

Answer (score 0):

Since every iteration of `aList` has to iterate over two lists, the complexity is not nice. Instead, generate indices first:

```
var bIndex: [String: B] = [:]
bList.forEach {
   bIndex[$0.id] = $0
} 

var cIndex: [String: C] = [:]
cList.forEach {
   cIndex[$0.id] = $0
} 

let filterModels: [FilterModel] = aList.map { aModel in
   return FilterModel(
      objA: aModel,
      objB: bIndex[aModel.bId],
      objC: cIndex[aModel.cId]
   )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct A {
    var id: String
    var bId: String
    var cId: String
}

struct B {
    var id: String
}


struct C {
    var id: String
}

let aList: [A] = [A(id: "a", bId: "b", cId: "c")] // 100 elements

let bList: [B] = [B(id: "a")] // 200 elements

let cList: [C] = [C(id: "a")] // 300 elements

struct FilterModel {
    var objA: A
    var objB: B?
    var objC: C?

    init(objA: A,
         objB: B? = nil,
         objC: C? = nil) {
        self.objA = objA
        self.objB = objB
        self.objC = objC
    }
}

var finalList: [FilterModel] = []
aList.forEach { a in
    let b = bList.first(where: { $0.id == a.id })
    let c = cList.first(where: { $0.id == a.id })
    finalList.append(FilterModel(objA: a, objB: b, objC: c))
}
```

If Records are coming through API. I would you to use pagination for the Response
With Compact map

```
 let finalList = aList.compactMap { a -> FilterModel in
        let b = bList.first(where: { $0.id == a.id })
        let c = cList.first(where: { $0.id == a.id })
        return FilterModel(objA: a, objB: b, objC: c)
    }
```

Comment: every where pagination is not available , so in that case there should be a solution for that